# Enable Port Forwarding for accessing server over the internet

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I want to visit this page on my server

```
http://192.168.2.53:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop
```

Since it's a dynamic IP, the above mentioned IP address keeps changing everytime I reset my connection. I replaced the IP with a DynDNS hostname I created

```
http://tmagrails.dyndns-ip.com/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop
```

However, I'm unable to access this page from a remote machine (any machine outside the server's network)

I was asked to forward the port 80 to 8080. I'm unable to do so as there is no port forwarding option in my router page. I use a UTStarcom UT300R2T modem/router.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Why don't you use http://tmagrails.dyndns-ip.com:8080/tma/majBtm/androidToDesktop ?

Comment: I tried that as well. Doesn't help.

Comment: try pinging the domain to make sure it's pointing to the right IP. From there you'll need to allow port forwarding on your router somehow and also let the port through any server side firewalls.

Comment: I'm not able to ping the server IP. I keep getting request timed out

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google's not finding me anything for the UT-300R2T.  Perhaps it's similar enough to the UT-300R2 that some of the info at [portforward.com's UT-300R2 page](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/UTStarcom/UT-300R2/UT-300R2index.htm) could help?